# Why the view doesn't show when I click the button in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am new to IOS , and I want to implement the album by `collectionView` in IOS.

When I click the `filebrowserbutton button` in `first View` , it will change to the `second View`(name:**AITCameraCollectionBrowser**).

There has two `button` and a `collectionView` in `AITCameraCollectionBrowser` like the following picture.

[image]

And the code of it's header file is like the following code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AITCameraCollectionBrowser : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *backButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *localAlbumButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionview;

@end
```

I have not load the picture from phone yet , so it should show the `view` like the above picture when I click the `change view button` in `first view`.

The code of `filebrowserbutton button` is like the following.

```
- (IBAction)filebrowserbutton:(id)sender {

    UIViewController *viewController = nil ;

    viewController = [[AITCameraCollectionBrowser alloc] initWithNibName:@"AITCameraCollectionBrowser" bundle:nil] ;

    viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Back", nil) style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] ;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

The above code of `button` in `first view` is no problem.

But it doesn't show anything when I click the `filebrowserbutton button` , it only has a `backBarButtonItem` on the top of screen.

So the problem is at second view , and I don't know why the `button` and `collectionView` is not show ?

Answer (score 1):

In you're header, or `.h` file, add the following code

```
- (IBAction)filebrowserbutton:(id)sender;
```

next, in you're `xib` or `storyboard` file, you have to connect `filebrowserbutton` from you're file's owner (by right-clicking the yellow, transparent box on the left of you're first picture) to the button, and choose `touch up inside`.

Comment: The `filebrowserbutton` is at `first view` , and I already add the code in `.h` file. The problem is at the `second view`.

Comment: @Martin As in 2 separate view files? If that's the case, then you don't need them, you can do them all in one file. Everything gets a lot more organized that way.

Comment: There has other thing to do in `first view` , so I have to use another `View` to show the `collectionView`.

Comment: @Martin You can combine 2 or more views into one `.xib` or `storyboard` file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `- (IBAction)filebrowserbutton:(id)sender;` to your header file and connect it to your button's `touchDown` method.

Comment: The `filebrowserbutton` is at `first view` , and I already add the code in `.h` file and connect to `touchDown` method. The problem is at the `second view`.